# Limiting the number of records Crystal Reports pulls from database

Tags: mysql, database, performance, crystal-reports, limit

So I have a report I created in Crystal Reports, in one section its pulling order numbers from a table but only displaying the most recent order number for a customer. This order table is very large and I'm concerned if someone was to run the report for a large date range that crystal would be pulling a lot data from the database when it doesnt really need to.

Is there a way to limit the amount of records crystal would pull for order number? Something kind of how the select top 20 * SQL statement works.

Ok heres a little more information about how I have everything laid out. 
I have an order table like this:

```html
<table border>
  <tr><td colspan=3>Table Name = Orders</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Date</td><td>Order Number</td><td>Customer Number</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2015-09-01</td><td>12345</td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2015-09-01</td><td>12346</td><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2015-09-01</td><td>12347</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2015-09-02</td><td>12348</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

and I have a customer table like this:

```html
<table border>
  <tr><td colspan=3>Table Name = Customers</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Customer Number</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>John</td><td>Doe</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>Sara</td><td>Thomas</td></tr>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>James</td><td>Jones</td></tr>
</table>
```

These two tables are linked and they will be added to my report to show something like this:

Date Range: Sept 1 - Sept 5

Customer: John Doe
Order#: 12348

Customer: Sara Thomas
Order#: 12346

Customer: James Jones
Order#: 12347

The list will show all the new customers added in a date range but the order number shows only the most recent order. What might happen is if I run the report for a date range from months ago (eg. March 5 - April 5), It will show all the new customers from that date range but it will pull all order numbers from March 5 to now and then only display the most recent order. All I want to do is restrict the order numbers so only the top 20 or so are pulled.

Comment: please try this type of query:-   select * from table order by **(id or date desc)** limit 20

Comment: if you have partition or your id is auto increment i recommended to add some condition for example where date between current_date - interval 1 day  and now()

Comment: sorry, I think I didn't do a very good job wording my questions...I need to be able to limit records pulled in Crystal Reports itself, I was just using the SQL statement as an example of what I'm trying to do in Crystal

Comment: have a look at this:
http://www.reportsyouneed.com/blog/understanding-group-sorting-and-crystals-top-n-reporting

or this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104520/top-n-in-view-or-crystal-reports

Comment: number of orders you want to limit is always same or every time you want to limit different orders?

Comment: I only need to see the most recent

Answer (score 0):

The same as "SELECT TOP 20 ..." in MySQL is LIMIT X at the end of the query, example:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 20;
```

Only get the first 20 lines. If you want to order ("ASC" for example) the result use the "LIMIT" after the "ORDER BY"